# AWS Websocket doesnt receive previous message until new message is sent

Tags: websocket, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Most of the time the messages are passed normally, but a couple messages in particular arent recieved until the recieving client sends a message. This happens **everytime** for specific methods/messages, but **not at all** for others.

Example: `user1` sends a message, `user2` then sends a message to receive message from `user1`.

---

**Related Material**

1. Deleted question: [websocket receives previous message only when new message is sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63658679/websocket-receives-previous-message-only-when-new-message-is-sent)
2. Github issue: [webSocket client does not receive messages before sending...](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/3147)

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? we are seeing similar behaviour

Comment: @BamdadDashtban No I didn't, kinda gaveup on it. What about you all, were you all able to progress on this issue?

Comment: We had to rewrite the lambda. I think it was an issue with the promises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ran into this issue and the solution had to do with how we wrote our promises. We initially used the sample code provided by Amazon

https://github.com/aws-samples/simple-websockets-chat-app/blob/master/sendmessage/app.js#L26

```
const postCalls = connectionData.Items.map(async ({ connectionId }) => {
    try {
      await apigwManagementApi.postToConnection({ ConnectionId: connectionId, Data: postData }).promise();
    } catch (e) {
      if (e.statusCode === 410) {
        console.log(`Found stale connection, deleting ${connectionId}`);
        await ddb.delete({ TableName: TABLE_NAME, Key: { connectionId } }).promise();
      } else {
        throw e;
      }
    }
  });
```

And I'm pretty sure having an async function as a map function doesn't work properly or reliably (for whatever reason. maybe this is documented somewhere), so we changed it to a simple for loop and it fixed the issue.

```
for(const connection of connectionData.Items) {
    const connectionId = connection.connectionId;
    ...same logic goes here
}
```

Comment: Haven't tested, but I swear if this works...

Comment: That sample code is valid, but you must continue with the sample by following it with `await Promise.all(postCalls);`, otherwise the Lambda may exit before it finishes processing. The `for/of` approach is good too, the difference is that for/of will post to each connection sequentially, while the AWS example posts to all in parallel and then waits for all to complete (if you do indeed followup with the `await Promise.all` call).

Comment: This worked perfectly for me also. Thank you so much @Programmer Unextraordinair